# Wordpress SEO plugin (by Yoast) and BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

I'm using Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin to generate breadcrumbs for my site. The problem is that when it comes to BuddyPress pages, the breadcrumbs can't see a member's profile page. Right now it shows `"Home > Members"` on the profile page when it should `"Home > Members > Whatever the member's name is"`.

Here's a snpashot of what I mean

[image]

Thanks to @brasofilo I was able to get it. Here's my final code

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'fix_bp_prifile_bc', 10, 2 );
function fix_bp_prifile_bc( $links ) {
    global $bp;
    $user_info = bp_get_user_meta( $bp->displayed_user->id, 'nickname', true );
    //check if we are viewing the profile  
    if($user_info):
        $links[] = array( 'url' =>'', 'text' =>$user_info );
    endif;
    return $links;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the filter [**`wpseo_breadcrumb_links`**](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/tags/1.4.1/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php).

In this example, I'm using the functions [**`bp_get_user_meta`**](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/buddypress/tags/1.6.4/bp-core/bp-core-functions.php) and [**`bp_loggedin_user_id`**](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/buddypress/tags/1.6.4/bp-core/bp-core-template.php), adjust as needed.

To check if the page is child of the *Members* page (in this example, `ID == 2`), I'm using the function `has_parent` [grabbed from here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-is_page-with-children-pages#post-648015).

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'buddy_crumbs_wpse_88889' );

function buddy_crumbs_wpse_88889( $links )
{
    // apply only in childs of Members page
    // in this example, Members has the ID of 2
    global $post;
    if( !has_parent_wpse_88889( $post, 2 ) )
        return $links;

    $user_info = bp_get_user_meta( bp_loggedin_user_id(), 'nickname', true );
    $links[] = array( 'url' => '', 'text' => $user_info );
    return $links;
}

function has_parent_wpse_88889($post, $post_id) 
{
    if ( $post->ID == $post_id ) 
        return true;
    else if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) 
        return false;
    else 
        return has_parent_wpse_88889( get_post( $post->post_parent ), $post_id );
}
```

[image: buddypress members breadcrumb]